# Excel Userform - Return Focus to ComboBox after hitting enter

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, focus, userform

I tried this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
         Me.ComboBox1.SetFocus
         Show_Information_Click
    End If
End Sub
```

Unfortunately when I hit enter, the "focus" shifts from the ComboBox1 to a CommandButton that I am using as a "Back" button for my form.

My ComboBox1 takes a user input name (which it autocompletes thankfully).  The person presses enter and a button right below it (which can be clicked instead) activates.  When the button has done it's thing, the "Back" button on my form is now the "focus" so that if the person hits enter again, it uses the "Back" button.  I would like to set focus back to the ComboBox1 so that when the user hits enter, it runs the code and returns focus to ComboBox1 so that they can type another name if they desire and go again.

I even tried putting the Me.ComboBox1.SetFocus at then end of the CommandButton's sequence of events and the "Back" button is still selected.

Thanks!

Comment: The code you posted has `Me.ComboBox1.SetFocus` before `Show_Information_Click`, have you tried it after?

Comment: Also, to avoid any change of focus, does your situation allow you to encapsulate your `Show_Information_Click` code inside a third Sub, perhaps `Show_Information_Inner`, and call that sub from both `Show_Information_Click` and `ComboBox1_KeyDown`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [tab order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733550(v=vs.60).aspx) and tab stop properties, they might help you (unless you want to use multiple controls, and want to use tab key to move between them).

For example, you can set the Tab stop property to False for every control on the form except your ComboBox. This way, after hitting enter, the focus returns there immediately.

You can set these from the properties window, no need to use code (but of course you can set them from code too).

Answer (score 1):

`SetFocus` is not the way to go, because anyway, the framework will change the focus *after* the execution of your routine. Instead, you can cancel the key's effect so that the focus wont change, like this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
         KeyCode = 0
         'Whatever other code that does not affect the focus again...
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!  This will come in handy with something I have lined up for the project on another form!

However, I need to run Show_Information_Click in order for the Userform to work as that's what populates information in various places on it.  I don't see the program running using the code above???

Comment: +1. This is the ONLY solution that actually works in Excel 2016, if you want to resolve loss of focus after various keydowns, such as arrow down and enter, and you have several comboboxes in a userform with the tabstop property set to true. I tried all the proposed solutions here, but to no avail [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442620/re-focusing-on-an-excel-userform-combobox]